# Gdal Calc quiet option not working

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

So I'm trying to use the quiet option for gdal calc, this is a cut of my code:

```
    call([sys.executable, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 
    Outer_Output_Raster, "--outfile=" + New_Outer_Raster, '--calc=-9998*
    (A>-9999)','--NoDataValue=-9999','--overwrite','--quiet'])
```

And I get the following error:

```
    gdal_calc.py: error: no such option: --quiet
```

But the documentation clearly lists this as an option, [see documentation here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html).

Does anyone have any suggestions or am I missing something completely?

For the record the rest of the code works exactly as intended, it is just the quiet option that isn't working.

Comment: Inside your `/gdal_calc.py`file, does the `--quiet` option exist? Otherwise perhaps you need to replace it with a more recent version if your GDAL is outdated, such as [this one](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py). Can't confirm if this will work for you so make sure you back up the original!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Joseph.

perhaps you need to replace it with a more recent version if your GDAL is outdated, such as [this one](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py). Can't confirm if this will work for you so make sure you back up the original!
Mine was indeed outdated.